# Install sogoupinyin on ubuntu 16.04LTS, with error 'Gtk/IMModule'

Tags: apt, language-support

I want to install sogoupinyin on my ubuntu 16.04 machine. Following was what I have done.

```
sudo apt remove fcitx
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot
sudo dpkg -i sogoupinyin*.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

those were msg reported when we typed 'dpkg' :

```
wangfrank@wangfrank-Inspiron-7447:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i ./sogoupinyin_2.1.0.0082_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for wangfrank: 
(Reading database ... 216172 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sogoupinyin_2.1.0.0082_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sogoupinyin (2.1.0.0082) over (2.1.0.0082) ...
Setting up sogoupinyin (2.1.0.0082) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
No such key 'Gtk/IMModule' in schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/50_sogoupinyin.gschema.override'; ignoring override for this key.
```

I followed [this link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=206234) but can't find sogoupinyin in the 'input method configure'. Could anybody help me? Thanks :)

----------second edit---------------

I just did what Serg said, change the schema file, and glib-compile.
But when I type 'dpkg' again, it throws this error again and the schema file was changed back... ???

----------third edit--------------
I typed sogou-session and got this, pending:

```
   wangfrank@wangfrank-Inspiron-7447:~$ sudo /usr/bin/sogou-session SESSION-PROGRAMNot get reply
/usr/bin/sogou-session: 15: exec: SESSION-PROGRAM: not found
(WARN-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx-config/fcitx-config.c:922) Invalid Entry: line 150 missing '='
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-classic-ui.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-freedesktop-notify.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xim.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkb.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkbdbus.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-pinyin-enhance.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-dbus.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-ipc.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-spell.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-table.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-pinyin.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-remote-module.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-unicode.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-kimpanel-ui.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-chttrans.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-fullwidth-char-enhance.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-autoeng-ng.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-lua.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-imselector.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-fullwidth-char.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-keyboard.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-sogoupinyin.conf
wangfrank@wangfrank-Inspiron-7447:~$ (INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-x11.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-punc-ng.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-sunpinyin.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-punc.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-notificationitem.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-cloudpinyin.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-autoeng.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-vk.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-clipboard.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-quickphrase.conf
(INFO-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-sogoucloudpinyin.conf
(WARN-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/frontend/xim/xim.c:161) Please set XMODIFIERS.
(ERROR-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/frontend/xim/xim.c:240) Start XIM error. Another XIM daemon named fcitx is running?
(ERROR-3580 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/instance.c:440) Exiting.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to have Sogou Pinyin working, you need to have `fcitx` installed and enabled. So that was a wrong move to remove it. Run `sudo apt-get install fcitx`, and after that open Settings -> Language  Support and set fcitx as your keyboard input method system. Once you do that, reboot.

[image]

Once you do that, you need to make the override schema just like it says in the article you linked. Quoting is very important. For instance, here's mine:

```
$ cat /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/50_sogoupinyin.gschema.override                               
[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard]
active=false
[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings]
overrides={'Gtk/IMModule':<'fcitx'>}
[com.canonical.indicator.keyboard]
visible=false
```

Save that and run `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`. This should be sufficient and then you can proceed with installing the `.deb` package.

Comment: @ Serg, it's so strange that after setting fcitx as your keyboard input method system, after changing schema file with glib-compile, when 'dpkg -i' was typed, error occurred again. And the schema file was changed as original 'Gtk/IMModule=fcitx'. Do you know what happened ? Thanks for your response.

Comment: @FrankWang  so, problem solved ?  解决了吗？

Comment: @FrankWang  OK, so after running `dpkg`  , check again - did  the package actually install ? Do `dpkg --get-selections | grep sogou`

Comment: unsolved yet, and I'm searching for the solution.

Comment: yes, installed. But, can't found it in input method configuration.

Comment: @FrankWang OK, so try to edit the file again, run `glib-compile-schemas` again. Instead of before installation, do it after installation. The `.deb` file may have a post-install script that overrides your changes.  Once you do that, try to run `sogou-session`

Comment: @FrankWang OK . . . I'm not quite sure what's going on,then.  I have to leave now, but let's continue the discussion tomorrow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53671/discussion-between-serg-and-frank-wang).